# Is it safe to assign a container using its own iterators?

Tags: c++

As an example:

```
string s = "123";
s.assign(find(s.begin(),s.end(),'2'), s.end());
```

Is the behavior of the above code defined? Or it leads to undefined behavior?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  This version of assign is [defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.assign#14) as

> ```
> template<class InputIterator>
>   constexpr basic_string& assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> ```
>
> *Constraints*: InputIterator is a type that qualifies as an input iterator.
>
> *Effects*: Equivalent to: return assign(basic_­string(first, last, get_­allocator()));

which shows a temporary computed before changes taking place.

Comment: "equivalent to" does not mean that an actual temporary has to be created. The semantics must be the same, though. And since the version shown is safe against self-assignment, the actual implementation must be too.

Comment: @MSalters. agreed.  I intended to comment on that then got lost in trying to determine how much of the allocator usage could be elided.

Comment: Note that this is specific to strings. For, say, vectors, it would be UB.

Comment: @T.C. , could you quote the standard?

Comment: @Adler, see [this table](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#tab:container.seq.req) to which the vector description refers.